# how to add/sub/div/mul more than 4 values? assembly language

Tags: assembly

very newbie question, how can I express arithmetic equations using more than 4 values?

**(14×3) +  16/4-3**

```html
ORG 0
MOV AL, E
MOV BL, 3
MUL AL, BL
;
MOV CL, 10
MOV DL, 4
DIV CL, DL
;
ADD AL, CL
MOV ??, 03 <--- what to put, DL is the last register
SUB AL, ?? <--- what to do 

END
```

Comment: You'll want to use a store or load command to move  data from a register into a location in memory.  Sorry I can't remember the specifics, which machine architecture are you using?

Comment: @edyrob amd, if thats what you asking for

Answer (score 0):

First, MUL and DIV only take 1 argument. Search for 'intel mul' and 'intel div' to see the instruction details:

*For 8 bits:*

Using an 8 bit register `r8` as argument (where `r8` is one of the 16 8 bit registers),

- `MUL r8` wil multiply `r8` with `al` and store the result in `ax`. This is because, for instance, multiplying 127 with 127 is bigger than 8 bits (but never more than 16).
- Similarly, `div r8` will divide `ax` by `r8`, put the result in `al`, and the remainder in `ah`.

*For a 16 bit argument:*

- `MUL r16` will multiply `r16` (a 16 bit register) with `ax`, and store the result in `dx:ax`, i.e., the high word in `dx`, and the low word in `ax`.
- Again similarly, `DIV r16` will divide `dx:ax` by `r16`, put the result in `ax` and the remainder in `dx`.

*Your calculation*

Calculating `14×3 + 16/4 - 3` is done like this:

```
    ; First term: 14x3
    mov al, 14
    mov bl, 3
    mul bl        ; ax = 42 (or, al=42 and ah=0)


    ; next we're going to DIV, which uses `AX`, so we better copy our result out of ax:
    mov cx, ax    ; or: mov cl, al


    ; Second term, 16/4 (16/3 would be more interesting!)
    mov ax, 16    ; we could mov al, 16 since ah is already 0
    mov dl, 4
    div dl        ; now al=4 and ah=0  (With 16/3, al=5 and ah=1!)


    ; Add to our result:
    add cl, al
;   adc ch, 0     ; take care of overflow if we want a 16 bit result


    ; calculate the 3rd term    
    mov al, 3     ; that was easy :-)

    ; and add the 3rd term to our result:
    sub cl, al    ; we could have done sub cl, 3
```

I hope you get the idea!

Comment: doesn't work for me anyways, i have to find other way to solve it as my lecture didnt cover that yet, thanks for effort tho :/

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work for you? I'm happy to explain anything, and I am quite sure there is no other way to do it!

Comment: when i put the following code into microSIM (to execute the code) it simply doesn't work. it doesnt matter if i type it up or just copy&paste, i got "expected AL,BL,CL,DL or [] got CX" error.

Comment: Aha, a (broken) simulator. Ok, if you change `cx` and `ax` to `cl` and `al` respectively, it should work fine (only 2 lines of code to change).

Comment: yeah this part worked this time, but then there is a problem with "div dl"

Comment: Change that to `div al, dl` (which is not valid Intel assembly by the way!)

Comment: i tried it already, then again there is an error with mov cl, al  saying "Use PUSH AL POP CL instead of MOV CL,AL" lol..

Comment: i did it lol, i put >10s into registers and rest of it just left without any registers and it worked

Comment: it worked for me, as I put all <10 numbers without register, I dont know if thats how it supposed to be but hey, at least it work :v